Excel script conditionalformating 'set formula' not working as expected
I wrote a script with conditionalformatting rules, everything works fine. But I have some lines that don't work when I run the script... unless I go to Conditional Formating ->manage rules, where I see the rule was created correctly. When I edit it and click 'Apply', the rule begins to work. This is the code:
// Create custom from range M2:M198 on selectedSheet
conditionalFormatting = table1.getColumn("clase cargada").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getRule().setFormula('=AND(M2<K2,L2=\"OK\",I2=\"Dictando\",(HOY()-M2)>=7,M2<>0)');
conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#ff0000");
conditionalFormatting.setStopIfTrue(false);
conditionalFormatting.setPriority(0);

The formula created with the script is this:
=Y(M2<K2;L2="OK";I2="Dictando";(HOY()-M2)>=7;M2<>0)
(my language is Spanish)
I tried with two operators AND, but it is always the same: I need to edit the formula manually, and then it works without changing anything. M2 and K2 is a date in dd/mm/yyyy format, L2 and I2 is text.
I've checked all the data in the columns. If I write this formula in a new column of the table, it works fine (True/False).
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
I put below a little example about what I want:
Example
I provide more similar code, if it helps, with other rule (I have 6 rules in this excel script). This code works fine at the first try:
    let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    let conditionalFormatting: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormat;
    // Create custom from column Altas body on table table1
    conditionalFormatting = table1.getColumn("Altas").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
    conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getRule().setFormula('=AND(R2<=10,R2>=7)');
    conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#ffff00");
    conditionalFormatting.setStopIfTrue(false);
    conditionalFormatting.setPriority(0);

Thanks all!

Please try removing all conditional formatting settings first, then run the first script before adding other 6 CF rules. Does it automatically apply conditional formatting to the cells? If nothing changes, please try copying the data (without formatting) to a new workbook, create a table, and then test the script. I’ve encountered some strange issues with Excel tables before.

Problem solved! I wrote in the formula HOY() [in Spanish, ], instead of TODAY(). Thanks @taller !
